# How can I read the Image text of Invoice using Python

Tags: python

I have an issue. I need to read image text (Company Name - LZE Packaging) from Readable PDF. How can I do that?

This below code is for reading the PDF data. It cannot read image text.

```
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd
pdfreader= PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("F:\\study\\production planning\\PO_123456.pdf")
page = pdfreader.getPage(0)
pagecontent = page.extractText()
print(pagecontent)
```

[image]

Comment: The company name looks like an image. There won't be any text to read.

Comment: If this is an image format you should look for OCR solutions such as [this](https://pypi.org/project/invoice2data/) one